# javascript jQuery - Given a comma delimited list, how to determine if a value exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

given a list like:

```
1,3,412,51213,djdd@asdasd.net, blahblah, 123123123123
```

which lives inside of a input type"text" as a value:

```
<input type="text" value="1,3,412,51213,djdd@asdasd.net, blahblah, 123123123123, wow@wow.com" />
```

How can I determine if a value exists, like 3, or blahblah or wow@wow.com?

I tried spliting with inputval.split(',') but that only gives me arrays. Is search possible?

Comment: Is `3` the same as `"3"`, or should they be considered different?

Comment: @Patrick same, I think that's the issue which is why I can get this working... do I need to convert data[num][opts.selectedValuesProp] to an integert to be found in the array?

Comment: If you use a `.split()` solution as being proposed in most answers, every item in the resulting Array will be a String. So if you're comparing the *number* `3` to the *string* `"3"` using `jQuery.inArray()`, it will do a *strict* comparison, and fail. If you know that you'll always be comparing Strings to Strings, it won't be an issue. If you need to compare a Number to a String, you'll need to loop over the Array yourself, and do a more loose comparison using `==`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
if (jQuery.inArray(value, str.replace(/,\s+/g, ',').split(',')) >= 0) {
    //Found it!
}
```

The `replace` call removes any spaces after commas.
[`inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) returns the index of the match.

Comment: The parameters are `(value, array)` and return value is -1 if no matches are found.

Comment: Thanks, strange still not working though, here is the line I'm trying to replace given a few bug fixes:        if(str.search(query) != -1 && values_input.val().search(","+data[num][opts.selectedValuesProp]+",") == -1){

Comment: so I took your idea and updated to: if (jQuery.inArray(data[num][opts.selectedValuesProp], values_input.val().replace(/,\s+/g, ',').split(',')) >= 0) {
        console.log('found it')
       } but it isn't working

Comment: console output "s
4
3,4,9
NOT FOUND" given        console.log(query)
       console.log(data[num][opts.selectedValuesProp])
       console.log(values_input.val().replace(/,\s+/g, ','))

       if (jQuery.inArray(data[num][opts.selectedValuesProp], values_input.val().replace(/,\s+/g, ',').split(',')) >= 0) {
        console.log('found it')
       }

Comment: @SLaks this won't works if value is `values` . i mean multiple element.

Answer (score 6):

Utilizing jQuery:

```
var exists = $.inArray(searchTerm, $('input').val().split(',')) != -1;
```

`exists` is now an boolean value indicating whether `searchTerm` was found in the values.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = inputval.split(',');
var found = false;
for (var i=0; i<list.length; ++i) {
  if (list[i] == whateverValue) {
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

You can be extra picky about the value matching by using "===" if it must be of the same type.  Otherwise, just use "==" since it will compare an int to a string in a way that you probably expect.

Answer (score 0):

You'l want to use `var arr = theString.split(',')` and then use `var pos = arr.indexOf('3');`

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_indexof.htm

Comment: Isn't `indexOf` a method of the string type, not the array type? The link given would seem to bear that out.

Comment: Actually yes and no... since a string is an array of chars, it's essentially doing the same thing... perhaps a clearer link would suffice.

Comment: @Lazaroff: Only in IE.  @Dutchie432: That's totally wrong.  A string has nothing to do with an array of chars.

Answer (score 0):

This'll do it:

```
var val = $('myinput').val()
val = ',' + val.replace(', ',',').replace(' ,',',').trim() + ','; // remove extra spaces and add commas
if (val.indexOf(',' + mySearchVal + ',' > -1) {
    // do something here
}
```

And it makes sure start and end spaces are ignored too (I assume that's what you want).

Comment: This answer makes significant assumptions. What suggests in the question that the spaces aren't significant?

Comment: Part of the string to be searched is `, blahblah,`. I think it's fair to assume that the OP wanted to search for `blahblah`, not `<space>blahblah`. I'm sure s/he will correct me if I'm wrong.